# Connected to internet on ppp0 in raspberry pi 3 but commands like ping, curl not working

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, linux, internet, ppp

Using wvdial to connect to the internet.
This is my **/etc/wvdial.conf**

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2
Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","airtelgprs.com"
Stupid Mode = 1
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Baud = 460800
New PPPD = yes
Modem = /dev/gsmmodem
ISDN = 0
Phone = *99***1#
Password = { }
Username = { }
```

After running the command `sudo wvdial`, ppp0 pops up on my network interfaces i.e. Running `sudo ifconfig ppp0`, I get the following output.

```
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
      inet addr:100.104.130.91  P-t-P:10.64.64.64  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
      RX bytes:380 (380.0 B)  TX bytes:437 (437.0 B)
```

After this I'm able to ping google using the command `ping -I ppp0 google.com` but when I try normal ping i.e. `ping google.com`, I don't get any response

Answer (score 3):

solved by entering the following command
`sudo route add default dev ppp0`